# Returning IPv6 addresses from DNS server in C#

Tags: c#, dns, ipv6

I am facing some unusual problems migrating my application to work in IPv6 environments.

I'm using .NET remoting to connect to a remote service supplying a hostname. That hostname (ipv6.dt112979.company) is registered on my DNS server (running on a Windows 2003 Server with IPv6 enabled in the network card and in the DNS) as an AAAA host.

The problem is that everytime I try to connect to that server a get a "No such host is known.". I've setup Wireshark and no DNS query is being issued. I've done a "ipconfig /flushdns" and the same result is observed.

So, I've created a simple application which simply does:

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("ipv6.dt112979.company");
```

And the result is always "No such host is found".

I've done a NSLOOKUP and the result is:

```
nslookup ipv6.dt112979.company
Server:  company-dev03.company
Address:  10.200.10.207

Name:    ipv6.dt112979.company
Address:  fe80::a5c3:bfde:5ece:e833
```

Do you have any idea of what the problem might be?
I've tested this with .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 and the problem is the same.
Tests were made in a Windows 7 machine.

If I had a A record for the ipv6.dt112979.company then the call suceeds but only returns the IPv4 address.

Best regards,
Nuno Centeio

Comment: Are you certain IPV6 is installed and enabled on your development machine? If not, it is not surprising you are getting back the No Host exception message.

Comment: @GregoryABeamer Yes I'm sure. I'm printing OSSupportsIPv6 and it returns True. Also, I can use "ping -6 ipv6.dt112979.company" and prove with Wireshark that all communication is using IPv6.

Comment: I'm wondering... Can it be because I don't have a fully enabled IPv6 network? I think that I'm using Teredo in all hosts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
I was not in a fully enabled IPv6 network. I was relying on private addresses (FE80::) and, despite of being able to perform ping and nslookup, looks like Winsocks2 doesn't like that.

I've configured Cisco UBE to have a real IPv6 network and everything started working as expected.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`Dns.GetHostAddresses` returns an array of IPaddress-values, are you sure you are looping through all of them?

Also, if the local computer doesn't support IPv6, the IPv6-results are filtered from the list of results when using `Dns.GetHostAddresses`. You mentioned that you've ensured that the remote host supports IPv6, but are you sure your local host supports this as well?

Comment: I'm printing OSSupportsIPv6 and it returns True. I can't iterate through the result because the function throws a SocketException. My host supports IPv6... I'm able to ping the remote host with IPv6 (proved in Wireshark) also I'm able to remote desktop to other IPv6 hosts, ...